# Apply function over consecutive groups in vector

Tags: r, function, apply

I want to calculate meas of three consecutive variables [image]a vector.

Ex:
Vec<-rep(1:10)

I would like the output to be like the screenshot below:

Comment: How did you get a mean of 1.5 for 1:3 values

Comment: I have no idea. I must have done something wrong in excel.  I want means of 1:3, 4:7, 8:10...

Comment: Seems like you want `zoo::rollmean(1:15, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the following function to calculate means by groups of 3 (or any other number):

```
   f <- function(x, k=3) 
     {
       for(i in seq(k,length(x),k)) 
         x[(i/k)] <- mean(x[(i-k+1):i]) 
      return(x[1:(length(x)/k)])
   }
```

> > f(1:15) 
> >     [1]  2  5  8 11 14

Answer (score 1):

We can create a grouping variable using `gl` and then get the `mean` with `ave`

```
 ave(Vec, as.numeric(gl(length(Vec), 3, length(Vec))))
```

Comment: Can it be made so that the length will be 5 instead of 15? Like: 2, 5, 8, 11, 14?

Comment: @mad The `Vec <- 1:10` If you meant to get the mean of 5 consecutive values, change the `gl` to `gl(length(Vec), 5, length(Vec))`